# Dyslexia and IQ

Tags: learning, measurement, intelligence, reading, iq

**Background Information of my questions:**
At the age of eight I was "diagnosed" with Dyslexia, I am now 47. I went from not being able to read and barely able to write to a college reading level in 9 months. I was in a program run by a Mrs. Cooper in Pennsylvania. I have taken several different IQ tests during my lifetime and found the results vary widely. 
I have noted that in the last ten years or so Dyslexia seems to be an almost antiquated diagnosis and am very curious about the definition of dyslexia in current science and the correlation, if any, between Dyslexia and intelligence.

**Questions**:

- Is there any specific IQ test that is directed at measuring the IQ's of people with dyslexia?
- What is the correlation between having dyslexia and IQ?

Comment: From where do you draw the conclusion that it is an "antiquated" diagnosis?

Comment: Heh, IQ is probably more antiquated. Reading comprehension levels might be a better indicator. Regardless, be careful in that correlation does not imply causation. A lot of people who have dyslexia have to work harder in life and thus develop a stronger work ethic (if they don't give up early). I'd hypothesize that dyslexic reading skill would either go higher *and* lower than the average population reading skill as age increases, depending on whether the person tried harder or gave up.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at google: http://web.mit.edu/newsoffice/2011/dyslexia-iq-0923.html

I know several dyslexic researchers in computer science and cognitive psychology/neuroscience suffering of big difficulties with spelling for example. I think they that are arguably intelligent despite of the dyslexia !

As for the IQ tests, you should keep in mind that some modules (in the weschler test for ex.) are oriented toward language skills (e.g., analogies), some toward general knowledge and some others toward performance (e.g., memory, visual reasoning).

I don't know to which extent dyslexia could impact each of these modules, but that could explain the differences you observed between tests (i.e. the relative importance they give to language compared to other skills).